# Replacing all NA numbers in a list with the list's mean

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm totally new to R, and I've been trying to replace the `NA` values with the mean value for each column. I've tried a lot of options. but none seems to work. I've tried this one and many similar ones but i keep on getting: `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`.

```
script<-function() {
for (i in names(data)) {
        data[[i]][is.na(data[[i]])] <- mean(data[[i]], na.rm=TRUE);
    }
}
```

But then after a while I thought I'd just count the columns and came up with this:

```
script<-function() {
    for (i in 1:20) {
        data[[i]][is.na(data[[i]])] <- mean(data[[i]], na.rm=TRUE);
    }
}
```

which doesn't show any errors, but doesn't seem to work either. When I type in data it's just the same data frame, but unedited. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your code is correct (though I'm not sure why it's wrapped in a function); maybe the problem is with your data.  What's the output of `str(data)`?

Comment: can you post example `data`?

Comment: @Aaron Note that their code is actually wrapped in a function but they didn't indent properly.

Comment: So it is.  @mnel demonstrates why that's the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your function is that it is a function, and thus the scoping only updates `data` within the scope of the function

running

```
for (i in names(data)) {
        data[[i]][is.na(data[[i]])] <- mean(data[[i]], na.rm=TRUE);
            }
       }
```

Not within a function will work as you wish.

Another approach would be to pass `data` as an argument

```
imputeMean <-function(data) {

    for (i in names(data)) {
    data[[i]][is.na(data[[i]])] <- mean(data[[i]], na.rm=TRUE);
        }
    return(data)
   }
# then you can save the result as a new object

updatedData <- imputeMean(data)
```

Note that for named lists (as `data` is), `[[<-` will copy every time, so you could get around this by using `lapply`

```
updatedData <- lapply(data, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: You forgot to add either a single line `data` or retrun(data) to avoid the problem of functions not retruning anything except the last evaluated result.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to make a function out of this (updated per *mnel* correction):

```
data.frame(lapply(data, function(x){replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x,na.rm=T))}))
```

Comment: Don't use `apply` on data.frames. This coerces to a matrix, and thus is not efficient memory wise and will coerce all columns to the same type. `lapply` is the way to go.